# Angular cant read cookie sent by backend

Tags: angular, google-chrome, jersey, jax-ws

I want to send a simple cookie from my backend using JAX-WS and Jersey to my Angular webclient but Chrome is unable to read or set the cookie.

```java
    @GET
    @Path("/cookie")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response getId(@CookieParam("session") String inp)
    {
        if (!keys.contains((inp))) {
            String cipher = randomize();
            keys.add(cipher);
            return Response.ok().cookie(new NewCookie("session", cipher)).build();
        }
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
```

this is how I did it on the backend side

```js
private httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Accept', 'text/plain')
        .set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

    private options = {
        headers: this.httpHeaders
    };

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getId(){
    return this.httpClient.get(this.apiUrl+'session/cookie', this.options);
  }
```

and this is how I managed it on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

First you can double check wether if the API is providing data accordingly to the request with POSTMAN call. If So you can come to conclusion that there is nothing wrong in the API.

Secondly I see inside your `getId()` method while you are using the `httpClient` you doest actually subscribe the to the `get` request.

You need to `subscribe` to the request in order to fetch values from the API and inititate the request.

```
getId(){
    return this.httpClient.get(this.apiUrl+'session/cookie', 
          this.options).subscribe((token)=>{
           console.log(token)
      });
  }
```

Comment: Postman gets the cookie when I send the the request but angular doesn't. Even when I subscribe to the getID() request.

Comment: Did you check the url correctly and it headers properly?